# git - Submodule issue with .gitignore

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore

I'm having the following error:

> git.exe submodule add  -- "D:/Programming/boost_1_50_0" 
>   "C:/Users/qwerty/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/framework"
>
> The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
>   C:/Users/qwerty/Documents/Visual Use -f if you really want to add it.
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)

none of my gitignore files specifies *C:/Users/qwerty/Documents/Visual* even remotely.

When I try the -f flag I get the following message:

> Adding existing repo at 'C:/Users/qwerty/Documents/Visual Studio
>   2010/Projects/ framework' to the index fatal:
>   'C:/Users/qwerty/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/framework' is
>   outs ide repository Failed to add submodule
>   'C:/Users/qwerty/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/ framework'

Comment: What happens when you escape the spaces with `\`? It should work without escaping them since the paths are between double-quotes, but who knows... - There's also a space between `Projects/` and `framework` in you `add -f` path.

Comment: I tried with '?', it didn't help. the space was accidentally created during posting.

Comment: Aw shit, my comments wasn't correctly parsed. I meant parsing with \.

Comment: OK! now it works. I replaced the full "...framework" path with "" when framework is the current working directory. Very strange... Thanks though.

Comment: You can answer your question and accept it then. ;) -- (I made few mistakes in my previous comment: comment* escaping*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by replacing the command:

> git.exe submodule add -- "D:/Programming/boost_1_50_0"
>   "C:/Users/qwerty/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/framework"

with:

> git.exe submodule add -- "D:/Programming/boost_1_50_0" ""

Whereas `C:/Users/qwerty/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/framework` is the current working directory.